# Website not resizing properly across resolutions. Media query or percentages?

Tags: html, css, resize, media-queries

New to CSS, HTML and Java but about to finish my first website. Apologies if this has been answered before but I've been driving myself crazy for days trying to solve this issue.

I created my site in 1366 x 768 and therefore tailored the max-width/height accordingly, but since testing the site on a Macbook air (resolution 1440x900), I'm having issues with resizing and white space around the content.

I updated max-width to 1440 which seemed to have sorted the horizontal white space, but the space beneath my footer remains no matter what I do.

Is there a way to resize up and down with resolutions? Are media queries the answer or am I gonna have to go back and redesign my site?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this style:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) if you are not very familiar with responsive design. Each `div`gets from `.col-md-1` class. (The sum is equal to 12).

With this **Grid System** you can see the elements in each resolutions fine.

Answer (score 0):

in the CSS you can add multiple @media screen sizes and set padding and margins according to the size of the device they are using. for example the website im working on at the moment has different styling for 3 different device sizes.

```
    @media (min-width: 1366px) {
  body{
    width: 100%;
    clear: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

Something like this could be helpful